# Items Unit Price Caluclation

Tags: dynamic-programming, x++, ax

I have two items

```
Item A Qty =1 and unit Cost Price(up) is 60

Item B Qty =1 and unit Cost Price(up) is 40

    Total Cost Price(cp) is 100

    Overhead 10 % over cp (may vary as per requirement) 100*10/100 = 10
cp + 10 = 110
Markup   10 % over overhead(may vary as per requirement) 110*10/100  = 11
cp + 10 +11 = 121
Now Customer has agreed to pay 110 instead of 121 so I have to change CP of items based on unit Cost price
    What I did is Item A 60-((60/100)*(121-110)) which is Up - (up/cp* diff) = 53.4
Item B is  40-((40/100)*(121-110)) which is Up - (up/cp* diff) = 35.6

    Now my cp became 89
Overhead 10 % over cp (stated above overhead %) 89*10/100 = 8.9
cp + 8.9 = 97.9
Markup   10 % over overhead(stated above mark up %)  97.9*10/100= 9.79
cp + 8.9 +9.79 = 107.69
    Now Customer agreed to pay 110 and my calculation by changing the unit price is getting 107.69
    I have to change the unit price of the items to meet the customer price.
```

It is not purely Ax related question but surely a touch would be required in the logic building of X++

Any Suggestions on this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Simple I got total Cost Price of 121 and Customer Agreed 110 I have change unit price*qty to meet Customer Agreed price,its all about logic

Comment: You need to be more specific than that.
What have you done so far, where, and what did not work.
Also you need to put up a specific question, "Any suggestions" does not count as a question.

Comment: This looks like a reverse percentage problem (math issue, see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/440576 for an answer), not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking back from your new price of 110...

Take off your markup of 10%...

```
110/1.1 = 100
```

Take off your overhead of 10%...

```
100/1.1 = 90.9090
```

Your split is a nice easy 60/40 so item 1 (round however you see fit)

```
90.9090 * 0.6 = 54.5454
```

Item 2

```
90.90 * 0.4 = 36.3636
```